# C++ Member Function Pointer Definition

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c++11

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct B {
    template <class C, class M, class T>
    void call1(C (M::*member)(), T *instance) {
        std::function<void()> fp = std::bind(member, instance);
        fp();
    }

    template <class C, class M, class T>
    void call2(C (M::*member), T *instance) {
        std::function<void()> fp = std::bind(member, instance);
        fp();
    }

    void foo() {
        call1(&B::func, this); // works
        call2(&B::func, this); // works

        call1(&B::func2, this); // Error: no matching member function for call to 'call2'
        call2(&B::func2, this); // works
    }

    void func() {
        std::cout << "func\n";
    }

    void func2() const volatile {
        std::cout << "func2\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    B{}.foo();
}
```

It seems that the later version don't accept functions with extra cv qualifiers.

What is the difference between specifying a function member pointer like this `C (M::*member)()` and like this `C (M::*member)`?

Comment: I didn't even know `C (M::*member)`  is valid syntax...

Comment: The point is that `call1` won't accept functions with cv-qualifiers, while `call2` allows that.

Comment: Unrelated but why bother using `std::bind` instead of just calling the member function directly? `(instance->*member)();`

Comment: @Snps sorry, that was my mistake. I've fixed it.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The parens in that case is redundant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's simplify to just considering the difference between:

```
template <class C, class M> void f(C (M::*member)());
template <class C, class M> void g(C (M::*member));
```

In `f`, `member` is a pointer to a member function of `M` returning taking zero arguments and returning `C`. If you called it with `&B::func`, the compiler will deduce `M == B` and `C == void`. Straightforward.

In `g`, `member` is just a pointer to a member of `M` of type `C`. But, in our case, `&B::func` is a function. So the impact here is just dropping the pointer. We deduce `M == B` again, whereas `C` becomes `void()` - now `C` is a function type. This is a *less specialized* version of `f` in that it allows for more kinds of members. `g` can match against functions that take arguments, or against pointers to members, or, relevantly, against *cv*-qualified member functinos.

Let's consider as an example an overloaded function and how it would get deduced differently (this was the original problem in your question, which has since been edited, but is still interesting):

```
struct X {
    void bar() { }
    void bar(int ) { }
};
```

When we do:

```
f(&X::bar);
```

Even though `&X::bar` is an overloaded name, only one actually matches `C (M::*)()`. The one that has `M == X` and `C == void`. There is simply no way that the overload of `bar` taking an `int` matches the template type. So this is one of the acceptable uses of passing an overloaded name. This deduces fine.

However, when we do:

```
g(&X::bar);
```

Now, there are *two* perfectly vaild deductions. `C` could be both `void()` and `void(int)`. Since both are valid, the deduction is ambiguous, and you fail to compile - with an error that doesn't really make this particularly clear.

---

Now back to your example:

```
call1(&B::func2, this); // Error: no matching member function for call to 'call2'
call2(&B::func2, this); // works
```

The type of `&B::func2` is `void (B::*)() const volatile`. Since `call1` deduces on a member function type that takes no args and isn't cv-qualified, the type deduction simply fails. There is no `C` or `M` to get those types to match.

However, the `call2` deduction is fine since it is more generic. It can match *any* pointer to member. We simply end up with `C = void() const volatile`. That's why this works.

Comment: Is there a way to create a function pointer, that can accept parameter overloads but would disregard cv-qualifiers? That is, let the generalized version `C (M::*member)` accept arguments and ignore cv-qualifiers. If I specify arguments i.e. `C (M::*member)(A1, A2)`, I need to overload these caller functions with `C (M::*member)(A1, A2) const` and `C (M::*member)(A1, A2)  volatile` respectively.

Comment: @Crossfire Just make a type trait like... `template <class T> struct is_func_const : std::false_type { }; template <class R, class... Args> struct is_func_const<R(Args...) const> : std::true_type { }; template <class R, class... Args> struct is_func_const<R(Args...) const volatile> : std::true_type { };` and then you can use SFINAE.